# Visual Studio Code code-completion against Sandbox Org with Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

How do I tell Visual Studio Code to use the Symbols from the Sandbox org?

I would like to develop Apex using Visual Studio Code, and get code completion based on the configuration / meta-data in a Sandbox org.

How can I get Visual Studio Code to provide Apex code completion against a Sandbox Org using Salesforce DX?

Comment: Standard `CTRL+Space` is not working? Note that Lightning completion is not supported yet.

Comment: Salesforce has published a preview version of the CLI and the VS Code extensions to allow you to develop against non-scratch orgs. Worth a look: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Develop-Against-Any-Org-in-Visual-Studio-Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The latest release of the Salesforce Extensions for VS Code and the
>   Salesforce CLI added a preview of basic support for developing against
>   non-scratch orgs. This means you can now use VS Code with your
>   package.xml file against Scratch Orgs, Developer Edition Orgs, etc.

You will need to install the preview release of the Salesforce CLI and enable the preview features in VS Code. You can do this by running the following commands:

```
 sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
```

Next you need to enable the feature in VS Code.

To open your user and workspace settings, use the following VS Code menu command:

- On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
- On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings

Set the following setting in your user settings:

```
 "salesforcedx-vscode-core.change_set_based_tools.enabled": true
```

Close and open VS Code and create a project.

To create a project with a manifest run from the command palette:

```
 SFDX: Create Project with Manifest
```

Alternatively, you can use the CLI to create the project:

```
 sfdx force:project:create --projectname myproject --manifest
 cd mychangeset
 code .
```

Change a setting to force the commands to work against API version 43:

```
 sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=43.0
```

If you want to connect to a sandbox org, edit file:

```
sfdx-project.json
```

Set sfdcLoginUrl to:

```
https://test.salesforce.com
```

Authorize the org via the command palette:

```
 SFDX: Authorize an Org
```

The new project you created came with a default manifest file located at:

> manifest/package.xml

Right-click this file and select the command

```
 SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org
```

Reference:

- [Develop Against Any Org in Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Develop-Against-Any-Org-in-Visual-Studio-Code)