# SFDX: create project using manifest not available

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I have visual studio code installed in my desktop and updated SFDX to its latest version. However, when I open up the command palette for 'Create project', I am seeing only the following two options

'Create Project'

'Create and Setup Project for ISV debugging'.

[image]

I am not seeing the option of 'Create Project using manifest'. I need this option so that I can develop against a sandbox.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Visual Studio Code? I also do not see the option, and realized I'm on 1.18. Waiting on compliance to upgrade, as the VSC Marketplace entry states that 1.26 is required.

Comment: have you updated all salesforce plugins in Visual studio cod?

Comment: @DavidReed, I am using the 1.28 version of VS Code. And I have updated all Salesforce plugins in VS Code.

Comment: @DavidReed, your solution helped. I have updated VS Code to 1.28.2 and now the command palette is showing the option 'Create Project with Manifest'.

Comment: That's good to know. I'll add it as an answer if I can reproduce your success, since I'm having the same problem!

Answer (score 4):

This issue appears to be related to version dependencies in Visual Studio Code and the Salesforce DX Extension Pack, rather than the SFDX command-line tool itself. Having the latest version of SFDX does not make this command available in Visual Studio Code by itself.

The [SFDX Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) documents a minimum Visual Studio Code version of 1.26.

To successfully get access in the VSC command palette to the "Create Project with Manifest" operation, it was necessary to upgrade to the latest version of Visual Studio Code and also to explicitly install the latest version of the plugin [Salesforce CLI Integration for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core). While part of the Extension Pack, this extension had either not been installed or had been disabled in my installation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the answer you are looking for then

[Develop Against Any Org with VS Code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Develop-Against-Any-Org-in-Visual-Studio-Code)

This is included in the newest version of the Salesforce Extensions for VS Code however

Comment: Balaji is asking about a new feature in SFDX that supports direct development against a sandbox.

Comment: In that case is this what he is looking for? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230969/visual-studio-code-code-completion-against-sandbox-org-with-salesforce-dx

Comment: That's probably a comment you should direct to Balaji, not me. You can comment on any post when you reach 50 reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. However, my issue is that I am not seeing the option "SFDX: Create project with manifest" option from command palette and I am not sure how to get that option show up in the Ctrl-Shift-P palette window. I want to be able to do that from VS Code itself, not from SFDX CLI.

Comment: Make sure your extensions are updated. After I updated mine and reloaded the option appeared in the Command Palette. Before this recent update you had to install a prerelease version of the CLI to get these features. Just reference the article I linked. If that doesn't work I honestly have no idea as I can't reproduce the issue myself.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli did you get this sorted? I had to use all the steps on the Troubleshooting page on the VS Code Extensions Wiki https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Troubleshooting to get the commands to appear.

Comment: @JodieM Yes, this is resolved. I had upgraded both SFDX and VS Code to the latest and then it started working. My VSCode is at 1.30.0 and my SFDX is at 6.44.0.